# How did I manage to define a XAMPP Apache extra directory outside of the usual conf settings? Can't find evidence

Tags: php, apache, xampp, config

I can access Apache through my browser, either `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` to access php files in root directory of `D:\Applications\XAMPP\htdocs`. However, I can navigate to `http://127.0.0.1/projects/` or `http://localhost/projects/` to access files in `D:\Documents\projects`. But **HOW**? How have I configured this to happen?

As far as I can see, I have no aliases in `D:\Applications\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf`. The document route is still `htdocs`, in the same file (`D:\Applications\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf`). I have no virtual hosts in `D:\Applications\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`.

Windows search through text files cannot find any reference to the search term `/projects` (nor `\projects`)within `D:\Applications\XAMPP\apache` text files.

Where did I define `D:\Documents\projects` as an accessible folder for Apache by navigating to `http://localhost/projects/`?

Answer (score 0):

Not even 5 minutes after asking, after hours of trying, I suddenly discovered the answer.

I do have an alias.

In `D:\Applications\XAMPP\apache\conf\httpd.conf` I wrote the line `Include "conf/alias/*.conf"` which means that I can define aliases in `D:\applications\xampp\apache\conf\alias` such as with 'D:\applications\xampp\apache\conf\alias\projects.conf' which define a basic alias to `D:\Documents\projects` with the code:

```
<Directory "D:/Documents/projects">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted

</Directory>

Alias /projects "D:/Documents/projects"
```